# How to add a global action in Sonata Admin?

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

Well, I have a fairly basic problem with Sonata Admin in my Symfony2 project.

I have a "products" list view with every product sold on my web store. On the top right "actions" menu, I have the default actions, with a single action named "Add new".

[image: List view in sonata admin]

I just want to add more actions next to "Add new": custom actions like "remove promo prices from all products", or "remove all products evaluations".

I don't want a "batch" action, I want a "global" action leading to a custom DB query.

All I find in the doc is related to batch actions or "single line action". Is there a way to do what I want ?

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Create and configure a custom admin extension](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/2-3/doc/reference/extensions.html) and override the `configureActionButtons(AdminInterface $admin, $list, $action, $object)` method to add custom actions:

```
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\AdminExtension;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\AdminInterface;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Route\RouteCollection;

class CustomGlobalActionsExtension extends AdminExtension
{
    public function configureActionButtons(AdminInterface $admin, $list, $action, $object)
    {
        return array_merge($list, [
            ['template' => 'admin/custom_action.html.twig']
        ]);
    }

    public function configureRoutes(AdminInterface $admin, RouteCollection $collection)
    {
        $collection->add('custom_action', $admin->getRouterIdParameter().'/custom_action');
    }
}
```

```jinja
{# app/Resources/views/admin/custom_action.html.twig #}
<a class="btn btn-sm" href="{{ admin.generateObjectUrl('custom_action', object) }}">Custom Action</a>
```

See also https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/2-3/doc/cookbook/recipe_custom_action.html

Comment: Yeah ! Thanks Wouter ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Is syntax changed a little bit and it is important to call the parent method:

```
/**
 * @param $action
 * @param null|object $object
 * @return array
 */
public function configureActionButtons($action, $object = null)
{
    $buttonList = parent::configureActionButtons($action, $object);
    $buttonList['create_custom'] = [
        'template' => 'admin/action/button.html.twig'
    ];

    unset($buttonList['not_wanted']);

    return $buttonList;
}
```